# How can I solve JPA infinite reference loop?

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, jpa, recursion

How can I solve JPA infinite reference loop?

As shown below, poiCategory includes parent and children. (I attached it as a picture because I couldn't copy it in Intellij.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNV9F.png)

Create poiCategoryDto by calling:

```
    private static CategoryDto makeCategory(PoiCategory poiCategory) {
        return CategoryDto. builder()
                .id(poiCategory.getId())
                .name(poiCategory.getName())
                .parent(getCategoryParent(poiCategory.getParent()))
                .children(getCategoryChildren(poiCategory.getChildren()))
                .depth(poiCategory.getDepth())
                .build();
    }
```

getCategoryParent and getCategoryChildren are:

```
private static Set<CategoryDto> getCategoryChildren(Set<Category> children) {

        if (children == null || children.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }


        Set<CategoryDto> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (Category child : children) {
                result.add(CategoryDto.builder()
                        .id(child.getId())
                        .name(child.getName())
                        .parent(child.getParent() == null ? null : getCategoryParent(child.getParent()))
                        .children(child.getChildren() == null ? null : getCategoryChildren(child.getChildren()))
                        .depth(child.getDepth())
                        .build());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

```
private static CategoryDto getCategoryParent(Category parent) {

        if (parent == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return CategoryDto. builder()
                .id(parent.getId())
                .name(parent.getName())
                .parent(parent.getParent() == null ? null : getCategoryParent(parent.getParent()))
                .children(parent.getChildren() == null ? null : getCategoryChildren(parent.getChildren()))
                .depth(parent.getDepth())
                .build();
}
```

To solve this problem, getCtegoryChildren has

```
        boolean recursiveLoop = parent.getChildren().stream().map(Category::getParent)
                .anyMatch(category -> {
                    if (category.getParent() != null) category.getParent().getId().equals(parent.getId());
                    return false;
                });

        if (recursiveLoop) {
            return null;
        }
```

added
getParent has

```
        List<Category> parents = children.stream().map(Category::getParent).toList();
        for (Category parent : parents) {
            boolean recursiveLoop = parent.getChildren().stream().anyMatch(category -> category.getParent().getId().equals(parent.getId()));
            if (recursiveLoop) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

has been added.

But dto returned null.

In structures such as A(parent = null, child=B), B(parent=A, child=C), C(parent=B, child=null)

B -> parent, child should exist, but I received a null value.

I wonder how I can properly receive the values ​​of A, B, and C while solving the infinite circular reference error.

Comment: 'To solve this problem' - to solve *what* problem, exactly? What made you assume you had a problem in the first place? Object may have a reference to child objects that point back to the parent. This is perfectly normal.

Comment: Set FetchType.LAZY on one side of the parent/children relationship

Comment: Lazy won't work with this code, as category.getParent().getId() will trigger fetching lazy relationships. As @crizzis mentioned, any issues with this model are NOT due to JPA which knows how to handle bidirectional relationships, but can be common in other serialization protocols (like REST JSON handling) which don't. If you are debugging a problem in Spring, chances are your model is being serialized to JSON and you have neglected to tell it how to handle circular references - there are many questions detailing the problem and how to use JSONIgnore on one side to break recursive loops

Comment: B's parent is A, and A's children are B. This is where infinite circular references occur.